# How to downgrade in android studio beta

Tags: android, android-studio

The current android studio version 0.8.9 brings a lot of issues, such as failing to import my dependencies keeps saying 'failed to find: dependency' , so how do you downgrade to example version 0.8.8

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should download Android Studio 0.8.8 again.